# Need a child under child dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Trying to add a child under a specific child in Json

```
myObj:any[] = [];

this.myObj  = {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "first_name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "last_name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
  }
}

addField(){
this.myObj.properties.push({'email':{'type': 'string'}}); // its not adding
}
```

ERROR TypeError: this.yourJsonSchema.properties.push is not a function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot `push()` onto an object, that is meant for arrays. Instead, just set its property directly:

```
this.myObj.properties.email = { type: 'string' };
```

EDIT: If you need to set the property based on a variable, you can use the `[]` syntax instead:

```
addStringField(field) {
  this.myObj.properties[field] = { type: 'string' };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, if I want to make the email text dynamic then .?